# Can't close the modal in Ionic-vue 5.5.2

Tags: vue.js, ionic-framework

in this version of @ionic/vue@0.5.5.2 I can't use a component and assign a reference (< Login ref="modal"/>) to it to close it in the Modal component (Login.vue), so I don't know how to close it from Login.vue. I leave my code:

Home.vue

```
<template>
<ion-page>
    <ion-header>
        <ion-toolbar>
            <ion-title>
                Title
            </ion-title>
        </ion-toolbar>
    </ion-header>

    <ion-content class="auth-form">

        <ion-grid>
            <ion-row>
                <ion-col align-self-center>
                    <ion-button @click="openModal" expand="block" color="primary">Registrarme</ion-button>

                    <span class="divider line one-line">o</span>

                    <span class="already">¿Tienes una cuenta?</span>

                    <ion-button @click="openModal" expand="block" color="danger">Iniciar sesión</ion-button>
                </ion-col>
            </ion-row>
        </ion-grid>
       
    </ion-content>

</ion-page>
</template>

<script>
import {
    IonContent,
    modalController,
    IonTitle,
    IonToolbar,
    IonHeader,
    IonButton,
    IonCol,
    IonRow,
    IonGrid,
    IonPage
} from '@ionic/vue';
import Login from '../views/Login.vue';

export default {
    name: 'inicio',
    components: {
       
        IonContent,
        IonTitle,
        IonToolbar,
        IonHeader,
        IonButton,
        IonCol,
        IonRow,
        IonGrid,
        IonPage
    },
    data() {
        return {
            modal: '',
            isOpen: false,
        }
    },

    methods: {
        async createModal() {
            this.modal = await modalController.create({
                component: Login,
                componentProps: {
                  title: 'Iniciar sesión'
              },
                
            })
        },
        async openModal() {
            await this.createModal()
            this.isOpen = true
            this.modal.present()
        },
        closeModal() {
            this.isOpen = false
            this.modal.dismiss().then(() => {
                this.modal = null;
            });
        },
    },
}
</script>
```

And my Login.vue:

```
<template>
<ion-page>
    <ion-header translucent>
        <ion-toolbar>
            <ion-title>{{ title }}</ion-title>
            <ion-buttons slot="end">
                <ion-button @click="cerrarmodal">Cerrar</ion-button>
            </ion-buttons>
        </ion-toolbar>
    </ion-header>

    <ion-content>

        <ion-list>

            <ion-item>
                <ion-label>Email</ion-label>
                <ion-input type="text"></ion-input>
            </ion-item>

            <ion-item>
                <ion-label>Contraseña</ion-label>
                <ion-input type="password"></ion-input>
            </ion-item>

        </ion-list>

        <ion-button color="primary" expand="block">Ingresar</ion-button>

    </ion-content>

</ion-page>
</template>

<script>
import {
    IonButtons,
    IonContent,
    IonButton,
    IonToolbar,
    IonHeader,
    IonTitle,
    IonList,
    IonLabel,
    IonInput,
    IonItem,
    IonPage
} from '@ionic/vue';
import {
    defineComponent
} from 'vue';

export default defineComponent({
    name: 'login',
    props: {
        title: {
            type: String,
            default: 'Super Modal'
        },
        closeMe: {
            type: Function,
            default: () => {
                ''
            }
        },
    },
    data() {
        return {
            content: 'Content',
        }
    },
    methods: {
        cerrarmodal() {
            this.$emit('close', {
                foo: 'bar'
            })
            // Not working
            this.$parent.closeModal()
        },
   
    },
    components: {
        IonButton,
        IonButtons,
        IonToolbar,
        IonList,
        IonInput,
        IonLabel,
        IonItem,
        IonPage,
        IonHeader,
        IonTitle,
        IonContent
    },
});
</script>
```

I've tried $ emit and $ parent.closeModal () but no luck, thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I resolved it by passing a prop "close" with the function closeModal and defining the prop "close" in the modal component and then calling it with a this.close

```
this.modal = await modalController.create({
                component: Login,
                componentProps: {
                  title: 'Iniciar sesión',
                  close: () => this.closeModal()
              },
                
            })
```

In modal component:

```
props: {
        title: {
            type: String,
            default: 'Super Modal'
        },
        close: { type: Function }
    },

cerrarmodal() {
            this.$emit('close', {
                foo: 'bar'
            })
            this.close()
            
        },
```

Comment: This may work, but it's clunky and doesn't use the built-in modalController designed to do this task. The other two answers here are the correct ones.

Comment: Thank you for this. I was looking for a way to emit an event without closing the modal. Passing a function as a prop helped me to achieve this. If you're looking to  pass data to the method, you can do this 'close: (data) => this.closeModal(data)' within componentProps.

Answer (score 10):

I confirm that the best and simple way to solve this is calling `dismiss()` function of `modalController`.

First we must import `modalController` in our modal component:

```
import { modalController } from "@ionic/vue";
```

Next we can close modal like this:

```
async function close() {
  await modalController.dismiss();
}
```

**Important**: I use await because `dismiss` return a promise so it's important use it.

Comment: This is the simplest way to close the modal from WITHIN the modal code

Comment: Agreed. Works for me every time.

Comment: This worked great for me. I'm using a modal to view a thumbnail image in full screen and my modal has a delete image button. So I was trying to emit an event and an image URL to the parent of the modal so it could go handle the delete.  That worked just fine but the modal would not go away. I was trying to dismiss the modal by setting the `:is-open` attribute to false after emitting. Using the `modalController.dismiss();` worked really well.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can call

```
modalController.dismiss()
```

to close any open dialog... also the emit should have worked, didn't see that code

Comment: This is the right answer. Call this within your modal, and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!-- ./modal.vue -->

<template>
  <ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar>
      <ion-button shape="round" fill="clear" @click="modalController.dismiss()">
          <ion-icon slot="icon-only" :icon="arrowBackOutline" />
        </ion-button>
    </ion-toolbar>
  </ion-header>
  <ion-content class="ion-padding">
    {{ content }}
  </ion-content>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { IonButton, IonHeader,  IonToolbar, IonContent } from '@ionic/vue';
import { arrowBackOutline } from 'ionicons/icons';
import { modalController } from "@ionic/vue";

export default {
  name: 'Modal',
  components: { IonButton, IonHeader, IonToolbar, IonContent },
  setup(){
    const content = 'Content';
    return {
      content,
      modalController,
      arrowBackOutline,
      IonHeader,
      IonToolbar
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).